# VBA For Loop Scraping Data into New Worksheets

Tags: vba, loops, excel, for-loop

I am doing a little data scraping in excel and trying to paste the data into new worksheets with the following code:

```
Sub ZillowScrape()
'
' ZillowScrape Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+z


    For x = 1 To 5
    Worksheets("URLs").Select
    Worksheets("URLs").Activate
    mystr = "URL;http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/332-Blanca-Ave-Tampa-FL-33606/45111195_zpid/"
    mystr = Cells(x, 1)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x

   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
    'CommandType = 0
    .Name = "01000_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "3,4,5"  '---> Note: many tables have been selected for import from the website
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next x
End Sub
```

I keep getting the error "Run Time Error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error" for line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
```

Comment: I'm guessing that your QueryTable isn't getting created, and then your With statement fails because your trying to set properties on an object that doesn't exist. Try breaking the code up, by setting the QueryTable into a variable, and then checking to see if the variable has a value or not. e.g. `Set qryResults = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))`. If the variable is empty, then you can focus on why the Add method isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in this code:

```
mystr = "URL;http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/332-Blanca-Ave-Tampa-FL-33606/45111195_zpid/"
mystr = Cells(x, 1)
```

I suppose the solution is this :

```
 mystr = "URL;http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/332-Blanca-Ave-Tampa-FL-33606/45111195_zpid/"+Cells(x,1).value
```

Comment: Or maybe: `mystr = mystr & Cells(x, 1).value`